# How to get BIRT REGEX MATCH syntax correct

Tags: javascript, regex, birt

I am trying to ensure a given Birt parameter contains exactly one, two or three 4-digit years csv.
So these would be good:

```
2017
2017,2018
=2017
=   2017,2018,   =  2019
2019,2020,2021
```

and these would be bad

```
abc
2019,2018,2017,2016
2019,dddd,2020
```

I tried this:

```
if(BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,"^ *?=? *?\d\d\d\d *?=? *?(, *?=? *?\d\d\d\d *?=? *?)?(, *?=? *?\d\d\d\d *?=? *?)?$"))
{
yearsValid=true;
} else {
yearsValid=false;
}
```

but even if the parameter is just 4 digits such as 2020, it never comes back true.

I am doing this in the open script for a data set.
It appears to work fine in notepad++

As a further data point here, these all failed to compile in the javascript in Birt that I tried to put in the bottom of the OPEN for the data set.. note that the 'try this' worked GREAT in notepad++:

```
//try this  ^=? *\d{4}(?:[, =]+\d{4}){0,2}$  

//generalDebug01 = BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,"\\d\\d" )); 

//generalDebug01 = BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,/\d\d/ )); 

//generalDebug01 = BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,/\\d\\d/ )); 

//generalDebug01 = BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,/^=? *\d{4}(?:[, =]+\d{4}){0,2}$/ )); 

//generalDebug01 = BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,BirtComp.test(params["Fiscal Year"].value,/^=? *\\d{4}(?:[, =]+\\d{4}){0,2}$/ ));
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? This is more a Birt javascript regex question than a regex question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for your validation:

```sh
^\W*\d{4}(?:\W+\d{4}){0,2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZT7h9y/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\W*`: Match 0 or more non-word characters
- `\d{4}`: Match 4 digits
- `(?:\W+\d{4}){0,2}`: Match 0 to 2 more instances of 4 digit numbers that separated by 1+ non-word characters
- `$`: End

Just based on your examples, this regex may also work for you:

```
^=? *\d{4}(?:[, =]+\d{4}){0,2}$
```

Comment: Thank you - the second worked in a superior fashion